# How to set up layout model attribute in thymeleaf with spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

The layout header (route path - '/**') Should retrieve some navigation menu data from a service and display it But I don't know where to put this attribute as there is no controller for this nagigation menu layout fragment template. The @ModelAttributes seems not be the right solution whenever the route is changed from the '/' to anywhere else.

What should be the strategy or pattern to inject an attribute to the layout (parent) template without creating a @ModelAttributes in each child and passing up to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) to handle all the layout logic.

Comment: Exactly what I need to know. Thanks!